# summon typeclass for singleton type

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to find the typeclass instance for a singleton that belongs to a sealed trait hierarchy

```
@ {
   sealed trait Foo
   case object F1 extends Foo
   case object F2 extends Foo

   trait Do[A]{
      def something(a:A):String
    }
    object Do{
      implicit def apply[A : Do] = implicitly[Do[A]]
      implicit object f1 extends Do[F1.type]{
           def something(a:F1.type) = a.toString
      }
      implicit class Syntax[A](a:A){
          def something(implicit d: Do[A]) = d.something(a)
       }
     }

  }
defined trait Foo
defined object F1
defined object F2
defined trait Do
defined object Do
@ val f:Foo = F1
f: Foo = F1
@ f.something
Main.scala:118: diverging implicit expansion for type cmd6.Do[cmd11.Foo]
starting with method apply in object Do
f.something
  ^
Compilation Failed
```

I tried with shapeless.Witness.Aux[F1.type]:

```
implicit def f1[A](implicit w:Witness.Aux[F1.type]) = new Do[w.T]{
           def something(a:F1.type) = a.toString
      }
```

But I got the exact same error

this works though

```
F1.something == "F1
```

Comment: `F1.something` works for me if I `import Do._`

Comment: You are calling `something` on an object of type `Foo`, not `F1.type` and there is no instance of `Do` for `Foo`, I think that can be a problem here, although I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: yeah, I ended up doing a "manual dispatch" on `Syntax.something`, couldn't make it with typeclasses